# Empty reply from server when i want to make a snapshot in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new in Elasticsearch. I have an index and I want to make a snapshot of it. So I started doing it, following [this instruction](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/modules-snapshots.html) in documentation.

But when I execute the first command:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_backup {"type": "fs"}'
```

I get this error curl: (52) Empty reply from server

What am I doing wrong?

Elasticsearch version is 2.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to create a repository using curl is like this:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_backup' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "location": "/your/path/to/repo",
    "compress": true
  }
}
'
```

You also need to make sure that your `elasticsearch.yml` file contains the following setting:

```
path.repo: /your/path/to/repo
```

Comment: Seems like it will work. What can be a location in my case? Right now it says, that:  "reason" : "[my_backup] location [/tmp] doesn't match any of the locations specified by path.repo because this setting is empty"